# Mocking EF extension method using mockablequery.moq - Does not work

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, moq, xunit

I have the following unit test that needs to mock the EF extension method `.ToListAsync` with `moq`. Since `moq` can't mock static methods and since extension methods are static methods I resorted to use the `mockableQuery.moq` library. But the `System.NotSupportedException` still pops up complaining about the usage of the extension method.

I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
using System.Reflection.Metadata;
using FluentAssertions;
using LanguageExt;
using LanguageExt.UnsafeValueAccess;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MockQueryable.Moq;
using Moq;
using xxx.Application.Features.Users.Queries.GetAllUserTypes;
using xxx.Application.Interfaces.Services;
using xxx.Domain.Entities;

namespace xxx.UnitTests.Application.Features.Users.Queries
{
    public class GetAllUserTypesQueryUnitTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public async Task Handler_Should_ReturnAllUserTypes()
        {
            // Arrange
            List<AppUserType> userTypes =
            [
                new AppUserType { UserTypeId = 1, UserTypeName = "Type 1" },
                new AppUserType { UserTypeId = 2, UserTypeName = "Type 2" }
            ];

            Mock<DbSet<AppUserType>> mockSet = userTypes.AsQueryable().BuildMockDbSet();

            mockSet
                .Setup(m => m.ToListAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
                .ReturnsAsync(userTypes);

            Mock<IxxxDbContext> mockContext = new();

            mockContext
                .Setup(c => c.AppUserTypes)
                .Returns(mockSet.Object);

            GetAllUserTypesQueryHandler handler = new(mockContext.Object);

            GetAllUserTypesQuery query = new();

            // Act
            Option<GetAllUserTypesResult> result = await handler.Handle(query, CancellationToken.None);

            // Assert
            _ = result.IsSome.Should().BeTrue();
            _ = result.ValueUnsafe().UserTypes.Should().BeEquivalentTo(userTypes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to mock `DbContext` or `DbSet`. Use the in-memory provider instead. You aren't trying to test EF's internal workings. The in-memory provider will handle simple queries with far less code. For more complex queries you need a different provider, like SQLite in in-memory mode. Check the [Testing section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/) in the EF documentation

Answer (score 1):

There is a good reason why extension methods cannot be mocked, and that is because they *shouldn't* be. They operate on something concrete, and it is thus the latter which you need to mock. If you find yourself trying to mock an extension method, it's generally an indication that you're doing something wrong.

In your case, `ToListAsync` and the other methods of `QueryableExtensions` operate on `IQueryable`, which is the source of your data. `DbSet` is an `IQueryable`, and you've already mocked this. Remove the code where you're trying to mock that method, and your test should pass.